# Sql Procedure - Error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 56

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm getting the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 56
>   Incorrect syntax near 'p'.

when I try to run my SQL Procedure seen below. This Procedure is for a search area on my program, it allows the user to submit certain critera which it then uses to pull out all the data the user is looking for.

```
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@logging_ref as varchar(50) = NULL,
@summit_ac_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
@contract_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
@invoice_no as varchar(50) = NULL,
@paycert as varchar(50) = NULL,
@record_type as int = NULL,
@qs as varchar(50) = NULL,
@records as int = NULL,
@state as int = NULL
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'
    SELECT TOP(@records)
        r.r_id as ref,
        grossVal as gross,
        payCert as cert, 
        p.p_id as paid,
        -- Data Columns for Display --
            logRef as "Logging Reference", 
            db_recTypes.recordName AS "Record Type", 
            invNo as "Invoice No.", 
            invDate as "Invoice Date", 
            accNo as "Summit Account No.",
            db_accountNo.name as "Company Name", 
            contract as "Contract No.", 
            taxStatus as "Tax Status", 
            netVal as "Net Value", 
            vat as "V.A.T", 
            grossVal as "Gross Value",
            paycert as "Payment Certificate No.", 
            period as "Period", 
            paydate as "Anticipated Payment Date", 
            db_qs.name as "QS record sent to", 
            sentDate as "Date sent to QS",
            db_sentMethod.name as "Sent Via", 
            returnedDate as "Date Returned", 
            r.deleted as Removed, 
            lastModified as "Last Modified", 
            creationDate as "Date Created", 
            db_users.name as "Creation User",
            p.date as "Date Paid"
        --  Main Table to Reference --
            FROM db_records as r
        -- Proceed with SQL JOINs -- 
            JOIN db_recTypes
            ON db_recTypes.recordID = recType
            Join db_accountNo
            ON db_accountNo.com_id = accNo
            Join db_qs
            On db_qs.q_id = sentTo
            JOIN db_sentMethod 
            On db_sentMethod.v_id = sentVia
            Join db_users
            On db_users.u_id = R.u_id
            LEFT JOIN db_payments as p
            ON p.r_id = r.r_id
            WHERE 1 = 1 '
             IF (@logging_ref IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'AND logRef LIKE ''%'' + @logging_ref + ''%'
             IF (@summit_ac_no IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'AND accNo LIKE ''%'' + @summit_ac_no + ''%'
             IF (@contract_no IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'AND contract LIKE ''%'' + @contract_no + ''%'
             IF (@invoice_no IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'AND invNo LIKE ''%'' + @invoice_no + ''%'
             IF (@paycert IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'AND payCert LIKE ''%'' + @paycert + ''%'
             IF (@record_type IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'AND recType LIKE ''%'' + @record_type + ''%'
             IF (@qs IS NOT NULL) SET @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + N'AND db_qs.name LIKE ''%'' + @qs + ''%'

            DECLARE @lastToken NVARCHAR(100) =
                (
                CASE
                    WHEN @state = 1 THEN ' r.deleted = 0'
                    WHEN @state = 2 THEN ' p.date IS NOT NULL' 
                    WHEN @state = 3 THEN ' p.date IS NULL'
                    WHEN @state = 4 THEN ' r.deleted = 1'
                END
                )
            SET  @SQL = @SQL + CHAR(13) + CHAR(10) + @lastToken

        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL,
            N'@logging_ref as varchar(50),
              @summit_ac_no as varchar(50),
              @contract_no as varchar(50), 
              @invoice_no as varchar(50),
              @paycert as varchar(50), 
              @record_type as integer, 
              @qs as varchar(50),
              @records as int, @state as int',

            @records = @records,
            @logging_ref = @logging_ref,
            @summit_ac_no = @summit_ac_no,
            @contract_no = @contract_no,
            @invoice_no = @invoice_no,
            @paycert = @paycert,
            @record_type = @record_type,
            @qs = @qs,
            @records = @records,
            @state = @state     
    END
GO
```

Also does any one now how to get SQL Server 2014 to display the query that has been executed so that I can read what the query looks like?

### PRINTED Query

```
 SELECT TOP(@records)
        r.r_id as ref,
        grossVal as gross,
        payCert as cert, 
        p.p_id as paid,
        -- Data Columns for Display --
            logRef as "Logging Reference", 
            db_recTypes.recordName AS "Record Type", 
            invNo as "Invoice No.", 
            invDate as "Invoice Date", 
            accNo as "Summit Account No.",
            db_accountNo.name as "Company Name", 
            contract as "Contract No.", 
            taxStatus as "Tax Status", 
            netVal as "Net Value", 
            vat as "V.A.T", 
            grossVal as "Gross Value",
            paycert as "Payment Certificate No.", 
            period as "Period", 
            paydate as "Anticipated Payment Date", 
            db_qs.name as "QS record sent to", 
            sentDate as "Date sent to QS",
            db_sentMethod.name as "Sent Via", 
            returnedDate as "Date Returned", 
            r.deleted as Removed, 
            lastModified as "Last Modified", 
            creationDate as "Date Created", 
            db_users.name as "Creation User",
            p.date as "Date Paid"
        --  Main Table to Reference --
            FROM db_records as r
        -- Proceed with SQL JOINs -- 
            JOIN db_recTypes
            ON db_recTypes.recordID = recType
            Join db_accountNo
            ON db_accountNo.com_id = accNo
            Join db_qs
            On db_qs.q_id = sentTo
            JOIN db_sentMethod 
            On db_sentMethod.v_id = sentVia
            Join db_users
            On db_users.u_id = R.u_id
            LEFT JOIN db_payments as p
            ON p.r_id = r.r_id
            WHERE 1 = 1 
 AND p.date IS NULL
```

Comment: `PRINT` is your friend here. Always `PRINT` a dynamic query to see what's actually getting executed. This would have immediately allowed you to see that the `WHERE` clause is missing an `AND` before the final condition.

Comment: it'd be helpful if you pointed out where line 56 is, so we don't have to manually count.

Comment: I have added the AND. Now I get this error `Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified.`

Comment: You need to examine your dynamic sql. There error is somewhere in there. This is why everybody is telling to you use PRINT. We can help but you have to provide the information needed to help. Unless we can see what the actual sql is you are running you aren't going to get an answer.

Comment: It does have too many arguments specified. You're passing `@records` twice.

Comment: Thank you Jeroen... You solved it! Been staring at this query for the last hour. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lastToken misses `+ ' AND ' + @lastToken`

and `@records` argument of sp_executesql two times mentioned

Comment: I have added the AND. Now I get this error `Msg 8144, Level 16, State 2, Line 2
Procedure or function  has too many arguments specified.`

Comment: @MarcusITSupport, `@records` argument of sp_exec, first instance of it.

Answer (score 1):

First think to check when building dynamic Sql is quotes. Looks like 
`N'AND logRef LIKE ''%'' + @logging_ref + ''%'` and other similar rows lack pair of quotes at the end.